# Creating a single image of a flat surface from several images of different parts of it

Tags: images, image-processing, photoshop, orthophotography

Say there's a flat surface that's too big to capture in a single image. Is there some program that will assist with, or automatically stitch them together, accounting for scale, rotation, and the angle at which the pictures were taken? To be clear, the images overlap; each one has a part of the wall that is included in at least one other photo.

I also took a video slowly panning through the surface, trying to keep my phone as close as I could to being parallel to the wall, but I did it by hand so it's definitely not perfect. I mention this in case there's some program that can do it from a video, but not from a few pictures.

I've tried doing it manually in a photoshop-like program (Pixlr), but the small differences in the angles at which they were taken made it impossible to do correctly. I was able to decently align some parts of the images, but it would always leave other parts heavily unaligned.

Comment: How big is big? Have a look at Photoscan from Google. Its meant to digitise a photo by taking 5  overlapping images. It works well. It may work for your size.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am quite happy with Bimostitch on Android for landscapes, for not sure how it performs for flat surfaces.